# get icons for special paths in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icons

I am trying to get for special paths (home, desktop, applications, ...) the icons you can see is the side bar of the finder. I tried the iconForFile method of NSWorkspace but got blue folder icons instead.
Do you have any idea how I can get the other icons?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *fileType = NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(kToolbarDesktopFolderIcon);
NSImage *desktopToolbarImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:fileType];
```

If you command-double click (Xcode 3) or command-click (Xcode 4) on the `kToolbarDesktopFolderIcon` constant, you'll be taken to a file (IconsCore.h) that contains a whole bunch of constants for default system icons.  The special toolbar-style icons you're looking for are all in the same group.  `kToolbarDownloadsFolderIcon` will get you the white down arrow inside the green circle, `kToolbarHomeIcon` will get you the house icon, etc.

Comment: Hi Dave, As usual, the perfect answer I was looking for. Thanks